# 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192-битная Эллиптическая кривая

Tags: криптография

Есть ли 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192-битные эллиптические кривые?

Answer (score 0):

При помощи функций из библиотеки "CryptNextGen" **bcrypt.dll** можно получить список всех алгоритмов и размеры их ключей. Алго на эллиптических кривых это "Elliptic Curve", что в сокращённом виде **EC**. Они используются в купе в DH (Диффи Хельмана), в результате чего получаем **ECDH**.

Когда-то я писал программу, перечисляющую все алго шифрования, и на моей Win7 получил размеры ключей ECDH в диапазоне 256-521 бит, хотя чистый DH без кривых поддерживает ключи и размером 4096 бит. Вот лог этой программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут прям ответ нарушает все требования к вопросам. В терминале это текст, может привести его текстом? И код программы, возможно у автора вопроса будет другой вывод

Comment: Ну я смотрю вопрос "Crypt-->EC", а под рукой оказался исходник. Просто нажал PrintScreen и выложил. Если автору вопроса нужно что-то иное, то ответ всегда можно удалить. А код у меня на ассемблере, поэтому врядли ему пригодится.

Comment: Я не доверяю ECC, и если я и собираюсь использовать его, то только с ключом 1024+ бит.